# Cypher Query: Get Line Details Matching a Criteria

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to find paths of any length that fall within total distance range and total angle range and then return the list of nodes in each path.  Also, the path should not traverse a relationship between two nodes more than once.  Is it possible to do this with a single cypher query?

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
MATCH p=(:Foo)-[:followedBy*]->(:Foo)
WHERE
  ($minAngle <= REDUCE(s=0, x IN NODES(p) | s + x.angle) <= $maxAngle) AND
  ($minDist <= REDUCE(t=0, y IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) | t + y.distance) <= $maxDist)
RETURN p;
```

Assumptions:

- All relevant nodes have the `Foo` label.
- All relevant relationships have the `followedBy` type.
- When you make the query, you pass the parameters `maxAngle`, `minAngle`, `maxDist`, and `minDist`.

Note: a `MATCH` clause will automatically filter out matches that would reuse the same relationship, satisfying your prohibition against "more than once" relationship traversals.

Caveat: variable-length patterns (involving `*` in the relationship) can cause out-of-memory errors and/or take a very long time to complete. You may want to set a reasonable upper bound (e.g. `[:followedBy*..6]`).